# Adding extra rule to Python sorting

Tags: python

I'd like to sort members of a list based on their location in a string. But I'd also like them to be ordered from smallest to largest in terms of length.

Example code:

```
slist = ['ATSEVSPNSK',
 'AVSEHQLLHDK',
 'TPGKK',
 'LVQQWSVAVFLLSYAVPSCGRSVEGLSR',
 'FGSDDEGR',
 'PSPNTK',
 'NHPVRFGSDDEGR',
 'RLVQQWSVAVFLLSYAVPSCGR',
 'RAVSEHQLLHDK',
 'LVQQWSVAVFLLSYAVPSCGR',
 'EQEKK',
 'YLTQETNKVETYK',
 'RFFLHHLIAEIHTAEIR',
 'VETYK',
 'GKSIQDLR',
 'YLTQETNK',
 'FGSDDEGRYLTQETNK',
 'VETYKEQPLK',
 'GKPGK',
 'PSPNTKNHPVR',
 'FFLHHLIAEIHTAEIRATSEVSPNSK',
 'SIQDLRR',
 'AVSEHQLLHDKGK',
 'ATSEVSPNSKPSPNTK',
 'SIQDLR',
 'SVEGLSRR',
 'FFLHHLIAEIHTAEIR',
 'KEQEK',
 'EQPLKTPGK',
 'EQPLK',
 'NHPVR',
 'SVEGLSR']

sequence = 'MQRRLVQQWSVAVFLLSYAVPSCGRSVEGLSRRLKRAVSEHQLLHDKGKSIQDLRRRFFLHHLIAEIHTAEIRATSEVSPNSKPSPNTKNHPVRFGSDDEGRYLTQETNKVETYKEQPLKTPGKKKKGKPGKRKEQEKKKRRTRSAWLDSGVTGSGLEGDHLSDTSTTSLELDSRRH'
```

This is what I'm trying to improve:

```
slist.sort(key=lambda x: sequences.find(x))

slist
Out[9]: 
['RLVQQWSVAVFLLSYAVPSCGR',
 'LVQQWSVAVFLLSYAVPSCGRSVEGLSR',
 'LVQQWSVAVFLLSYAVPSCGR',
 'SVEGLSRR',
 'SVEGLSR',
 'RAVSEHQLLHDK',
 'AVSEHQLLHDK',
 'AVSEHQLLHDKGK',
 'GKSIQDLR',
 'SIQDLRR',
 'SIQDLR',
 'RFFLHHLIAEIHTAEIR',
 'FFLHHLIAEIHTAEIRATSEVSPNSK',
 'FFLHHLIAEIHTAEIR',
 'ATSEVSPNSK',
 'ATSEVSPNSKPSPNTK',
 'PSPNTK',
 'PSPNTKNHPVR',
 'NHPVRFGSDDEGR',
 'NHPVR',
 'FGSDDEGR',
 'FGSDDEGRYLTQETNK',
 'YLTQETNKVETYK',
 'YLTQETNK',
 'VETYK',
 'VETYKEQPLK',
 'EQPLKTPGK',
 'EQPLK',
 'TPGKK',
 'GKPGK',
 'KEQEK',
 'EQEKK']
```

Whether a larger version of a string in `slist` is sorted above or below a string that starts in the same location in `sequence` depends on its original position in `slist`. An example is `'LVQQWSVAVFLLSYAVPSCGRSVEGLSR'` being farther up the list than `'LVQQWSVAVFLLSYAVPSCGR'`, the opposite scenario is also true for other members of `slist`, some smaller strings are sorted above larger strings due to their original position in `slist`.

I'd like to keep my original manner of sorting. But I'd also like that among members of `slist` that start at the same location in `sequence`, the shorter strings are sorted above longer strings.

Any good way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include `len` each element in the sort key

```
slist.sort(key=lambda x: (sequence.find(x), len(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

[Python's default sort is stable](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts), so you can chain your sorts:

```
slist.sort(key=len)
slist.sort(key=sequence.find)
```

Comment: This won't work, because it first sorts by length, *then* by sequence location. Consider the list of tuples [(3, 4), (2, 1), (1,1), (2, 7), (-1, 2)]. If I sort by this list by the first index, then the second index separately, this is not the same as sorting by `key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1])`. This has nothing to do with sorting stability.

Comment: You need to start from the least significant key, so in your example, sort by `x[1]` then by `x[0]`. `t= [(3, 4), (2, 1), (1,1), (2, 7), (-1, 2)]; sorted(sorted(t, key=lambda x: x[1]), key=lambda x: x[0]) == sorted(t)` returns True

Comment: My point is that sorting twice separately will not always return the same result as sorting once with a multi-valued key. My example might not have been a concrete example of that.

Comment: Looking back at your comment, `sorted(t)` by default chooses the zeroeth index of each tuple as the sort-by value, so of course sorting by `x[1]` then by `x[0]` will return the same list as sorting by `x[0]` only. So of course `sorted(sorted(t, key=lambda x: x[1]), lambda x: x[0]) == sorted(t)` returns `True`. I think you just reaffirmed my point by example.